# Return Future fail when Option has None

Tags: scala, scala-cats, monad-transformers

I have below code which works fine

```
case class MainRequest(optionalVal: Option[String])

case class IntermediateResult(someVal: String)

case class FinalResult(param: String)

def process(param: String, intermediateResult: IntermediateResult): Option[String] = ???

def getFutureOfList: Future[List[Int]] = ???

def getFutureOfOption(param: Int): Future[Option[IntermediateResult]] = ???

def overallResult(mainReq: MainRequest): Future[Option[FinalResult]] = {
  (for {
    optionalOne <- OptionT(getFutureOfList.map(_.headOption))
    optionalTwo <- OptionT(getFutureOfOption(optionalOne))
  } yield {
    mainReq.optionalVal.flatMap(process(_, optionalTwo)).map(FinalResult)
  }).value.map(_.flatten)
}
```

But now , I need to change `overallResult` function so that it would return Future fail Exception when `mainReq.optionalVal` is `None` or `process(_,optionalTwo)` results in `None`. As much as possible, trying not to change the return type of function.

I tried below but can't fail future inside `yield`.

```
def overallResult(mainReq: MainRequest): Future[Option[FinalResult]] = {
  (for {
    optionalOne <- OptionT(getFutureOfList.map(_.headOption))
    optionalTwo <- OptionT(getFutureOfOption(optionalOne))
  } yield {
    mainReq.optionalVal match {
      case Some(contains) =>
        process(contains, optionalTwo) match {
          case Some(result) => FinalResult(result)
          case None => new RuntimeException("process(contains, optionalTwo) resulted in None")
        }
      case None => new RuntimeException("mainReq.optionalVal resulted in None")
    }}).value.map(_.flatten)
```

Comment: _"As much as possible, trying not to change the return type of function."_ I am a bit confused about this, since you want to return a failed future if the value is `None` why do you want to return a `Future[Option[FinalResult]]`, why not just `Future[FinalResult]`? - Or you want to return a `Success(Some(FinalResult))` if everything worked, a `Success(None)` if `optionalOne` and `optionalTwo` are `None` and a `Failure(CustomException)` if this `mainReq.optionalVal.flatMap(process(_, optionalTwo)).map(FinalResult)` returns a None?